# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource while viewing pop-up information

Tags: javascript, html, popup, openlayers

I have published a WMS service on my geoserver, and I am trying to create a web map by consuming that service and using open layers in such a way that when I click on the features, it gives me pop-up information. Below is the code that I am using

```js
//Create a wms layer 
let wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/<placeholder>/wms?',
      params: {'LAYERS': '<placeholder>:WEBGIS', 'TILED': true},
      serverType: 'geoserver',
    })
  });

// Create and Render map on div with zoom and center
class OLMap {
    constructor(map_div, zoom, center) {
      this.map = new ol.Map({
        target: map_div,
        layers: [       
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          wmsLayer
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat(center),
          zoom: zoom
        })
      });
    }
  }

// Create Overlay 
class Overlay {
    //Contrctor accepts map object, overlay html element, overlay offset, overlay positioning and overlay class
    constructor(map, element = document.getElementById("popup"), offset = [0, 0], positioning = 'bottom-center',   className = 'ol-tooltip-measure ol-tooltip .ol-tooltip-static') {
      this.map = map;
      this.overlay = new ol.Overlay({
        element: element,
        offset: offset,
        positioning: positioning,
        className: className
      });
      this.overlay.setPosition([0,0]);
      this.overlay.element.style.display = 'block';      
      this.map.addOverlay(this.overlay);    
      
    }
  }  

  let map = new OLMap('map', 5, [78.9629, 20.5937]).map;

  map.on('singleclick', function (e) {  
  let url = wmsLayer.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
    e.coordinate,
    map.getView().getResolution(),
    'EPSG:3857', 
    {
      'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
      'propertyName': 'sovereignt,scalerank,labelrank,type'
    }
  );
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((json) => {
        map.getOverlays().clear();
        let popup = new Overlay(map).overlay;
        popup.setPosition(e.coordinate);
        let feature = JSON.parse(json).features;
        if (feature.length) {
          let properties = feature[0].properties;
          let table = document.createElement('table');          
          Object.entries(properties).forEach((value) => {            
            let tr = document.createElement('tr');
            let td1 = document.createElement('th')
            td1.style.textAlign = "left";
            let td2 = document.createElement('td')
            td2.style.textAlign = "left";
            td1.innerHTML = value[0];
            td2.innerHTML = value[1];
            tr.append(td1);
            tr.append(td2);
            table.append(tr);
          });
          popup.element.append(table);
        } else {
          map.getOverlays().clear();
        }
      });
      
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.15.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 700px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.15.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>Open Layers</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> PopUp Test </h1>
    <div id = "map" class = "map"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

When I am opening the HTML page, the base map along with features, loads without any issues however, when I click on any feature to get pop-up information, I get the following error :

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/EndTerm/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=EndTerm%3AWEBGIS&LAYERS=EndTerm%3AWEBGIS&TILED=true&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&propertyName=sovereignt%2Cscalerank%2Clabelrank%2Ctype&I=151&J=129&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&BBOX=7514065.628545966%2C2504688.542848654%2C8766409.899970293%2C3757032.814272982' 
from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, 
set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

So I just wanted to know if there is any setting that I might be missing.

Comment: so, add some CORS headers to your server response - personally, I'd also be testing the page using a local HTTP server rather than opening the HTML file directly from the filesystem

Comment: Hey @JaromandaX, I am actually very new to geoserver and openlayers so am not really sure where and how to add CORS headers to server response. It would really be helpful if you can guide me on how to proceed further.

Comment: Liekly this is what you need: https://launchcodeeducation.gitbook.io/using-geoserver-with-openlayers/rendering-data-in-openlayers/enabling-cors-in-geoserver

Comment: @VikhyatGupta - you've shown absolutely nothing about the **server** - so, how can I show you squat?

Comment: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html#enable-cors